# Re-evaluate non volatile UDF automatically

Tags: excel, udf, vba

Say, we have the following non-volatile UDF:

```
Function Twice(ByRef x As Double) As Double
    Application.Volatile False
    Twice = 2 * x
End Function
```

which we enter in a cell `A1` with reference to cell `A2`, i.e. in `A1` we put:

```
= Twice(A2)
```

Furthermore, in `A2` we put the random function, i.e. in `A2` we put:

```
=RAND()
```

Now, if we re-calculate the sheet (say, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>), the value in the cell `A2` will change, but the UDF will not update, even though its reference has changed.

How can we make this UDF update automatically (i.e. without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) when its reference value changes?

Comment: Remove the line`Application.Volatile False` as @pnuts suggested and set the calculation of the workbook as automatic instead of manual

Comment: @pnuts Not stating explicitly `Application.Volatile False` is the same as stating it as it is the default setting.  I just put it here to be explicit in that I do not want the function to be volatile.

Comment: Define x as `Variant`.

Comment: Please do not change the edit. Your Question title should not have the description. The Post area is for that.

Comment: @pnuts  I want UDF to change only when the value in the cell to which it refers (in the example cell A2) changes.  I do not want it to change when, say a value in cell A3 changes, which what would happen if the function is volatile.

Comment: @user3964075  That seems to do the trick.  Thanks.  Would you care to expand your comment into an answer with perhaps some explanation on why this works?

Comment: @SiddharthRout  There are already some questions on re-calculation of UDFs - wanted to make clear that mine is not addressed by them.  Also, why do you keep capitalising almost every word in the title?

Comment: There you go.. I have uncapitalized them. :) You can make it clear in the post itself. The title area is not for descriptive text.

Comment: @Confounded sorry, but I can't give you detailed explanation. I think it's because you need the parameter to be of type `Range` to make it work. If you pass `A2+1` as the parameter it won't recalculate. Maybe someone else will find more universal solution.

Comment: @pnuts  No.  In my example, x depends on A2.  When a value (returned by a function) in A2 changes, I want UDF to re-evaluate.  If I make UDF volatile, it will revaluate when any value in any cell on the sheet changes.

Comment: @user3964075  OK,  I up-voted your comment.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3964075  Strange, by defining parameters as `Variant` seems to turn some functions into Volatile.  Need to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is what I consider a bug when you use Application.Volatile False with a Double argument that refers to a volatile formula.

If you remove the Application.Volatile False statement it works OK.

See https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/false-volatility-is-this-a-bug/
for a more detailed discussion of this and speculation as to the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This solution (as well as defining parameters as variant) has been offered in the comments to the OP, but I will accept you answer in order to close this question and since it offers further details and acknowledges this “strange” behaviour.